# php mysql sort results by order fetched

Tags: php, mysql

How can I order the results I get by the order of the ids in the array when using IN statement:

> SELECT id,name from table WHERE id IN (23, 33, 55, 2)

I want to get:

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 23 | name1   |
| 33 | name2   |
| 55 | name3   |
|  2 | name4   |
+----+---------+
```

in this order

Comment: Just to clarify, what he's trying to achieve is sorting on the CSV-list of IDs. So for example `(23, 33, 55, 2)` and `(2, 55, 33, 23)` will return the IDs in that order. Not just sorting by the id desc/asc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply add this at the end of your query:

```
order by field(id, 23, 33, 55, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a JOIN. It is not guaranteed to be returned in this order, but for MySQL this holds true most of the time:

```
SELECT table.id, table.name
FROM ( 
  SELECT 23 id UNION SELECT 33 id UNION SELECT 55 id UNION SELECT 2
) a
JOIN table
ON a.id = table.id
```

How is your order determined? If you can provide a sorting-function it gets easy.

Comment: +1 This was where I was going to go with it. I am uncertain though if the db would return the rows according to it's own whim in terms of order or follow the union in the subselect?

Comment: @Fluffeh: well, the "own whim" of the union-subselect is the order as-written. And MySQL usually leaves the order as is when joining (although it does not have to, and SQL usually operates on sets – i.e. no deterministic ordering)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT id,name from table WHERE id IN (23, 33, 55, 2) ORDER BY FIELD (id, 2, 23, 33, 55)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT t.id,t.name 
from 
    (select 23 as id,1 as rnk union all 
     select 33 as id,2 union all
     select 55 as id,3 union all
     select 2 as id,4 )input
join table t 
on   t.id=input.id
order by input.rnk
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT id,name from table WHERE id IN (23, 33, 55, 2) ORDER BY id = 23 DESC, id = 33 DESC, id = 55 DESC, id = 2 DESC` not a database specific solution but still works

Comment: Interesting approach :) Also possible: `ORDER BY id != 23 (ASC), id != ...`

Comment: I used it when I needed to order on a weird field combination which would change depending on another field, needless to say it was a very complex query to write

Comment: included the answer in case he actually wanted something more complex but tried to give a simplified example and the field approach wouldn't work

Comment: The reason this works is because MySQL converts boolean values to integers for sorting. So false becomes 0 and true becomes 1 (and 0 and 1 have a defined ordering)

Comment: I'm almost certain it works in most databases, not just mysql