# Select data from mysql in different order

Tags: php, mysql, select, fetch

I have data along with the ids 1,2,3,4,5 but these are not primary ids...
I want to fetch data in order like 4,3,2,1,5.
I cann't change the ids in database.If i use order by desc it will fetch 5,4,3,2,1.

Comment: Please show your data, your schema and what you really want to try to achieve. "order like 4,3,2,1,5" looks completely random.

Comment: you need some field you can sort with. some column which would help you to fetch in that order

Comment: This should be your answer [php mysql sort results by order fetched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459816/php-mysql-sort-results-by-order-fetched/12459958#12459958)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by field is one such way:

```
select * from TABLE order by FIELD(column_name,4,3,2,1,5) ;
```

You can look into this for more details:

[Field Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416153/order-by-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

you can use FIELD in order clause

```
order by FIELD(field_name,4,3,2,1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ORDER BY RAND()` for random order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT table.* FROM table  ORDER BY FIELD(id,4,3,2,1,5);
```